# PowerPoint “Bullets and Numbering” Corrupted

Tags: microsoft-office, fonts, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2016, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

Having a problem with bullets not showing up properly in PowerPoint 2016 on Windows 7; both are fully patched. So far I have tried (in order):

1. Replacing Fonts directory from a working computer - no luck
2. Running 'Restore default font settings' - no luck
3. Repairing Office 2016 - no luck

Below is what I am experiencing; the red notation is the problematic PC and the green is the working PC (and what I should be seeing.)

This happens for all users who log into the system so it is not profile related. Hoping to avoid a rebuild of the system.

[image: Screen capture]

Comment: have you tried re-installing powerpoint? Not that familiar with how bullet points work, but it's likely a seperate file from fonts. If you can find that, you can copy over the files from the working one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably missing the Wingdings font, or the font is damaged.

If you open Character Map, set the font to Wingdings and locate the characters you SHOULD be seeing and note the character codes, you can then switch to a normal font and check the same code positions.  You'll see that they match up with what you're seeing on the problem computer.

Comment: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts pointed to wingding.ttf while the file was wingding_0.ttf. Changing either to match corrected the problem - in the end, I renamed the file.